# TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: express

After I run my server i get: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined` . Initially I thought I was missing the next() parameter(after I saw a similar question here) and even after adding it I still get the error.

```
 app.get('/access_token', (req, res, next) => {
        let url = "https://sandbox.safaricom.co.ke/oauth/v1/generate?grant_type=client_credentials";
        let auth = new Buffer.from("7zmKTsK1s2Vjo1IoiW1qDww7607xvZxG: EEaR6xGC6cr2QuSP").toString('Base64');
    
        request({
            url: url,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic" + auth
            }
        },
            (req, res, next, body) => {
                res.send.json(body);    
            }
        )
    });
```

Comment: change `res.send.json(body);` to `res.json(body);`, does it work?

Comment: no, I get `TypeError: res.json is not a function`

Comment: Where is `request` imported from or otherwise initialized? If it is from [Node's built-in `http`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#httprequestoptions-callback), then the callback only receives one argument, `res`, which has different methods available to it than an Express middleware callback.

Comment: `const request = require('request');`